EXJavaScriptRuntime class overriding
``error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
`// Copyright 2018-present 650 Industries. All rights reserved.
`
#import <jsi/jsi.h>

#if __has_include(<reacthermes/HermesExecutorFactory.h>)
#import <reacthermes/HermesExecutorFactory.h>
#elif __has_include(<React-jsc/JSCRuntime.h>)
// react-native@>=0.71 has a specific React-jsc pod
#import <React-jsc/JSCRuntime.h>
// use_frameworks! transforms the dash to underscore
#elif __has_include(<React_jsc/JSCRuntime.h>)
#import <React_jsc/JSCRuntime.h>
#else
#import <jsi/JSCRuntime.h>
#endif

#import <ExpoModulesCore/EXJavaScriptRuntime.h>
#import <ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesHostObject.h>
#import <ExpoModulesCore/EXJSIUtils.h>
#import <ExpoModulesCore/EXJSIConversions.h>
#import <ExpoModulesCore/Swift.h>

namespace {

/**
 * Dummy CallInvoker that invokes everything immediately.
 * Used in the test environment to check the async flow.
 */
class SyncCallInvoker : public react::CallInvoker {
public:
void invokeAsync(std::function<void()> &&func) noexcept override {


  void invokeSync(std::function<void()> &&func) override {
    func();
  }

  ~SyncCallInvoker() override = default;
};

} // namespace

@implementation EXJavaScriptRuntime {
  std::shared_ptr<jsi::Runtime> _runtime;
  std::shared_ptr<react::CallInvoker> _jsCallInvoker;
}

/**
 Initializes a runtime that is independent from React Native and its runtime initialization.
 This flow is mostly intended for tests.
 */
- (nonnull instancetype)init
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
#if __has_include(<reacthermes/HermesExecutorFactory.h>)
    _runtime = facebook::hermes::makeHermesRuntime();

    // This version of the Hermes uses a Promise implementation that is provided by the RN.
    // The `setImmediate` function isn't defined, but is required by the Promise implementation.
    // That's why we inject it here.
    auto setImmediatePropName = jsi::PropNameID::forUtf8(*_runtime, "setImmediate");
    _runtime->global().setProperty(
      *_runtime, setImmediatePropName, jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(*_runtime, setImmediatePropName, 1,
        [](jsi::Runtime &rt, const jsi::Value &thisVal, const jsi::Value *args, size_t count) {
          args[0].asObject(rt).asFunction(rt).call(rt);
          return jsi::Value::undefined();
        })
    );
#else
    _runtime = jsc::makeJSCRuntime();
#endif
    _jsCallInvoker = std::make_shared<SyncCallInvoker>();
  }
  return self;
}

- (nonnull instancetype)initWithRuntime:(nonnull jsi::Runtime *)runtime
                            callInvoker:(std::shared_ptr<react::CallInvoker>)callInvoker
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    // Creating a shared pointer that points to the runtime but doesn't own it, thus doesn't release it.
    // In this code flow, the runtime should be owned by something else like the RCTBridge.
    // See explanation for constructor (8): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr
    _runtime = std::shared_ptr<jsi::Runtime>(std::shared_ptr<jsi::Runtime>(), runtime);
    _jsCallInvoker = callInvoker;
  }
  return self;
}

- (nonnull jsi::Runtime *)get
{
  return _runtime.get();
}

- (std::shared_ptr<react::CallInvoker>)callInvoker
{
  return _jsCallInvoker;
}

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)createObject
{
  auto jsObjectPtr = std::make_shared<jsi::Object>(*_runtime);
  return [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:jsObjectPtr runtime:self];
}

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)createHostObject:(std::shared_ptr<jsi::HostObject>)jsiHostObjectPtr
{
  auto jsObjectPtr = std::make_shared<jsi::Object>(jsi::Object::createFromHostObject(*_runtime, jsiHostObjectPtr));
  return [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:jsObjectPtr runtime:self];
}

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)global
{
  auto jsGlobalPtr = std::make_shared<jsi::Object>(_runtime->global());
  return [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:jsGlobalPtr runtime:self];
}

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)createSyncFunction:(nonnull NSString *)name
                                         argsCount:(NSInteger)argsCount
                                             block:(nonnull JSSyncFunctionBlock)block
{
  JSHostFunctionBlock hostFunctionBlock = ^jsi::Value(
    jsi::Runtime &runtime,
    std::shared_ptr<react::CallInvoker> callInvoker,
    EXJavaScriptValue * _Nonnull thisValue,
    NSArray<EXJavaScriptValue *> * _Nonnull arguments) {
      NSError *error;
      id result = block(thisValue, arguments, &error);

      if (error == nil) {
        return expo::convertObjCObjectToJSIValue(runtime, result);
      } else {
        throw jsi::JSError(runtime, [error.userInfo[@"message"] UTF8String]);
      }
    };
  return [self createHostFunction:name argsCount:argsCount block:hostFunctionBlock];
}

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)createAsyncFunction:(nonnull NSString *)name
                                          argsCount:(NSInteger)argsCount
                                              block:(nonnull JSAsyncFunctionBlock)block
{
  JSHostFunctionBlock hostFunctionBlock = ^jsi::Value(
    jsi::Runtime &runtime,
    std::shared_ptr<react::CallInvoker> callInvoker,
    EXJavaScriptValue * _Nonnull thisValue,
    NSArray<EXJavaScriptValue *> * _Nonnull arguments) {
      if (!callInvoker) {
        // In mocked environment the call invoker may be null so it's not supported to call async functions.
        // Testing async functions is a bit more complicated anyway. See `init` description for more.
        throw jsi::JSError(runtime, "Calling async functions is not supported when the call invoker is unavailable");
      }
      // The function that is invoked as a setup of the EXJavaScript `Promise`.
      auto promiseSetup = [callInvoker, block, thisValue, arguments](jsi::Runtime &runtime, std::shared_ptr<Promise> promise) {
        expo::callPromiseSetupWithBlock(runtime, callInvoker, promise, ^(RCTPromiseResolveBlock resolver, RCTPromiseRejectBlock rejecter) {
          block(thisValue, arguments, resolver, rejecter);
        });
      };
      return createPromiseAsJSIValue(runtime, promiseSetup);
    };
  return [self createHostFunction:name argsCount:argsCount block:hostFunctionBlock];
}

#pragma mark - Classes

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)createClass:(nonnull NSString *)name
                                constructor:(nonnull ClassConstructorBlock)constructor
{
  expo::ClassConstructor jsConstructor = [self, constructor](jsi::Runtime &runtime, const jsi::Value &thisValue, const jsi::Value *args, size_t count) {
    std::shared_ptr<jsi::Object> thisPtr = std::make_shared<jsi::Object>(thisValue.asObject(runtime));
    EXJavaScriptObject *caller = [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:thisPtr runtime:self];
    NSArray<EXJavaScriptValue *> *arguments = expo::convertJSIValuesToNSArray(self, args, count);

    constructor(caller, arguments);
  };
  std::shared_ptr<jsi::Function> klass = expo::createClass(*_runtime, [name UTF8String], jsConstructor);
  return [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:klass runtime:self];
}

- (nullable EXJavaScriptObject *)createObjectWithPrototype:(nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)prototype
{
  std::shared_ptr<jsi::Object> object = expo::createObjectWithPrototype(*_runtime, [prototype getShared]);
  return object ? [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:object runtime:self] : nil;
}

#pragma mark - Script evaluation

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptValue *)evaluateScript:(nonnull NSString *)scriptSource
{
  std::shared_ptr<jsi::StringBuffer> scriptBuffer = std::make_shared<jsi::StringBuffer>([scriptSource UTF8String]);
  std::shared_ptr<jsi::Value> result;

  try {
    result = std::make_shared<jsi::Value>(_runtime->evaluateJavaScript(scriptBuffer, "<<evaluated>>"));
  } catch (jsi::JSError &error) {
    NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:error.getMessage().c_str()];
    NSString *stack = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:error.getStack().c_str()];

    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ScriptEvaluationException" reason:reason userInfo:@{
      @"message": reason,
      @"stack": stack,
    }];
  } catch (jsi::JSIException &error) {
    NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:error.what()];

    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ScriptEvaluationException" reason:reason userInfo:@{
      @"message": reason
    }];
  }
  return [[EXJavaScriptValue alloc] initWithRuntime:self value:result];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (nonnull EXJavaScriptObject *)createHostFunction:(nonnull NSString *)name
                                         argsCount:(NSInteger)argsCount
                                             block:(nonnull JSHostFunctionBlock)block
{
  jsi::PropNameID propNameId = jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(*_runtime, [name UTF8String], [name length]);
  std::weak_ptr<react::CallInvoker> weakCallInvoker = _jsCallInvoker;
  jsi::HostFunctionType function = [weakCallInvoker, block, self](jsi::Runtime &runtime, const jsi::Value &thisVal, const jsi::Value *args, size_t count) -> jsi::Value {
    // Theoretically should check here whether the call invoker isn't null, but in mocked environment
    // there is no need to care about that for synchronous calls, so it's ensured in `createAsyncFunction` instead.
    auto callInvoker = weakCallInvoker.lock();
    NSArray<EXJavaScriptValue *> *arguments = expo::convertJSIValuesToNSArray(self, args, count);
    std::shared_ptr<jsi::Value> thisValPtr = std::make_shared<jsi::Value>(runtime, std::move(thisVal));
    EXJavaScriptValue *thisValue = [[EXJavaScriptValue alloc] initWithRuntime:self value:thisValPtr];

    return block(runtime, callInvoker, thisValue, arguments);
  };
  std::shared_ptr<jsi::Object> fnPtr = std::make_shared<jsi::Object>(jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(*_runtime, propNameId, (unsigned int)argsCount, function));
  return [[EXJavaScriptObject alloc] initWith:fnPtr runtime:self];
}

@end`

ive added
void invokeAsync(std::function<void()> &&func) noexcept override {

it doesn't work not sure what else I need to change but im trying to make a expo app build a an iOS app ive installed everything I need not sure what else im missing I can provide any code needed if asked
it will not run in Xcode either not sure if there is a way to fix it I don't want to rebuild this and it took over 3 months to make this app I can't afford to rebuild this and I have all my apple id credentials

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
